# Why won't my code enter into while loop after I enter a string?

Tags: java, methods

I had to do a bunch of methods in my code and then have it all go to the main method. Everything is working correctly, but when I enter in a string to the "getOrder" method it won't check to see if the string is true and then finish the rest of the code. Can someone please help me? I tried doing an if and else statement, but they didn't work either. thank you

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class App {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    //Get banner message
    welcomeUser();

    //Get product array
    String[] products = getProducts();

    //Get prouct order from user aka the LA
    getOrder(products);

    //Does the product exist?
    if(getOrder(products) == true) //yup it exists
    {
        //Get the *price*
        getPrice();
        double fPrice = getPrice();

        //Get the TAX
        getTax(fPrice);
        double tax = getTax(fPrice);

       //Get the total sale
        getTotal(fPrice, tax);

        //output the total sale
        double transaction =  getTotal(fPrice, tax);
        printTotal(transaction);

    }
    else
        System.out.print("Not found");


}

public static void welcomeUser()
{
    System.out.println("Hello! Welcome to the Fruit Market!");
}

public static String[] getProducts()
{
    String [] productList = new String [5];
    productList[0] = "Banana";
    productList[1] = "Pineapple";
    productList[2] = "Grapes";
    productList[3] = "Strawberries";
    productList[4] = "Kiwi";
    //System.out.println(Arrays.toString(productList));
    return productList;
}

public static boolean getOrder(String[] stuff)
{
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    String usersFruitChoice;
    System.out.println("Please enter a fruit you would like to buy.");
    usersFruitChoice = scan.nextLine();

    boolean valid = false; 

    while(!valid)
    {
        for (String stuff1 : stuff) {
            valid = stuff1.equalsIgnoreCase(usersFruitChoice);
        }        
   }

     return valid;

}


}
```

}

Comment: I have downvoted this question because there is far too much code here.  In order to make it clear exactly where your problem is, please remove any code that is not directly causing your problem, and if you can reduce it to ten lines or less, I will consider retracting the downvote.  See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: how do you know that it's not entering?

Comment: Does while(!valid) evaluate to while(true)? Should it be while(valid == false)?

Comment: @JoeC I took out every thing below the while loop. Sorry

Comment: @isaace when I type in strawberries and then hit enter nothing happens. I just keep hitting enter and my consistently runs.

Comment: Why doing every operation twice, e.g. `getPrice()`, `getProduct()`, etc are all done twice in a row ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider removing this line - it does nothing:

```
//Get prouct order from user aka the LA
    getOrder(products);
```

Comment: If this answer is correct consider marking it as a "correct answer"

Comment: It doesn't "do nothing".  It does something, even if it's the wrong thing.

Comment: after I took it out and then did what @AdilB did my program worked. Having the getOrder(products); was making my program repeat the same line twice

Answer (score 1):

The culprit seems to be your `for` loop:

```
for (String stuff1 : stuff) {
        valid = stuff1.equalsIgnoreCase(usersFruitChoice);
    }
```

This section of your code will iterate through your entire products array and will overwrite the value of `valid` if a later value in the array does not match whatever is in `usersFruitChoice`. Try entering `Kiwi` for `usersFruitChoice` and see if the code enters the `while` loop to verify that this error is occurring.

You can fix this by using a `break` statement if you found a valid entry that matches `usersFruitChoice`, as that will exit the loop early and not always cause the last value in the array to be checked against `usersFruitChoice`:

```
for (String stuff1 : stuff) {
        if (stuff1.equalsIgnoreCase(usersFruitChoice)) {
             valid = true;
             break;
        };
    }
```